# NMON analyze cpu and mem 1 day

Tags: monitoring, aix

I tried to analyze one day's worth of CPU and memory using nmon on AIX, but I have an error -- why? I also want to run it in background.

```
user@host(/home/user)$ nmon -s 900 -c 96 -m 96 -r "nmon report" -f -t -m /home/user
Change Directory failed: No such file or directory
Directory attempted was: 96
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given the `-m` ("change directory") option twice: once with a value of `96` and a second time with a value of `/home/user`. Remove `-m 96` from your command. To run it in the background, simply append `&`. The result:

```
nmon -s 900 -c 96 -r "nmon report" -f -t -m /home/user &
```